# How to create .xml file of all the contacts from device. or how to import .vcf file into .xml file

Tags: swift, xml

I want to create a .xml file of all the contacts of ios device and send the file again at the other end I want to parse the xml and create the contacts, note:- can use .vcf as intermediary but for this project I have to create .xml file.

Comment: Please provide any code attempts you have made for this question

Comment: I solved the issue : -

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by writing a separate Reader and Writer :- 
Reader func :-

```
     func contactsToVCARDXMLGenerator()-> AEXMLDocument{

    let store = CNContactStore()
    var contacts : [CNContact] = []
    let contactsXML = AEXMLDocument()
    let root = contactsXML.addChild(name: "root")
    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch:[CNContactVCardSerialization.descriptorForRequiredKeys()])
    do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (contact, stop) -> Void in
            contacts.append(contact)
        })
    }
    catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    do {
        let vcarddat = try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: contacts)
        let vcardAsString = String(data: vcarddat, encoding: .utf8)
        print(vcardAsString!)
        let contactsArray = vcardAsString!.components(separatedBy: "END:VCARD")
        for index in 0..<contacts.count {
            root.addChild(name: "contact", value: "\(contactsArray[index])")
        }
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return contactsXML
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 func xmlToRemindersEntries(xmlDoc : String) -> Bool{
    //print(xmlDoc)
    do{
        let doc = try AEXMLDocument.init(xml: xmlDoc)
        var vcardString = String()
        for contact in doc.root.children {
            vcardString += "\(contact.value!)\nEND:VCARD\n"
        }
        let contacts = try CNContactVCardSerialization.contacts(with: vcardString.data(using: .utf8)!)
        for each in contacts{
            let mutCpoy = each.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact
            let store = CNContactStore()
            let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
            saveRequest.add(mutCpoy, toContainerWithIdentifier:nil)
            try! store.execute(saveRequest)
        }

    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }
   return true
}
```